# Why does `std::for_each_n` not compile?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    std::for_each_n(v.begin(), 2, [](int n) { });
}
```

With gcc 9.2.1 (`-std=c++17`), this fails to compile:

```
error: could not convert 'std::for_each<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, main()::<lambda(int)> >(__first, __first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >::operator+(__n2), (__f, main()::<lambda(int)>()))' from 'main()::<lambda(int)>' to '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >'
3900 |  return std::for_each(__first, __first + __n2, __f);
```

A peek inside `for_each_n` tells me that it calls

`std::for_each(v.begin(), v.begin() + 2, ...)`

But apparently, `for_each` returning a function object is not compatible with `for_each_n` returning an iterator.

How do I use `for_each_n` ?

Comment: Seems like a compiler issue, it works fine in gcc 10.0.1 20200307 and clang 5.0.0 (and above).

Comment: @Darhuuk it doesn't work in clang 9.0.0 on godbolt

Comment: This code compiles here without further ado. gcc version 9.2.1 20200130 (Arch Linux 9.2.1+20200130-2)

Comment: @M.M Hm, strange, it does on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MQfN61vtudRj7uTX).

Comment: Sounds like a bug in GCC's implementation. `std::for_each()` does not return an iterator, it returns the function object, so `std::for_each_n()` should not be trying to return what `std::for_each()` returns, it should be returning `__first + __n2` instead, eg: `InputIt __end = __first + __n2;  std::for_each(__first, __end, __f); return __end;`

Comment: @Darhuuk perhaps it's a libstdc++ library bug, I think godbolt uses libstdc++ for its "clang" option, and indeed the error messages for the "clang 9.0.0" and "clang trunk" builds show gcc-9.2.0/lib. The error messages from godbolt 9.2 gcc differ to OP's too (it fails in overload resolution for `for_each_n`)

Comment: This is how the implementation looks like that actually ships with GCC 9.2.1: `auto __last = __first + __n2; std::for_each(__first, __last, std::move(__f)); return __last;` (from `/usr/include/c++/9.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h`)

Comment: [Works with MSVC](https://www.godbolt.org/z/aGLs6e) fails with clang and gcc, so basically bug in library implementation. Adding [execution parameter](https://www.godbolt.org/z/MWrUsu) doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem with the library implementation.

[`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) returns a copy of the function object that was passed in.

[`for_each_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n) returns an iterator to the first element past the end of the range that was iterated over (`v.begin() + 2` in this example).

These two types are not compatible, and having `for_each_n` return the result of a `for_each` loop should not compile.

Comment: Would you elaborate "`for_each_n` return the result of a `for_each` loop"?